What are the key distinctions b/w specifying the lattice parameter using angstrom (Å) and atomic unit (au) measurements within the Quantum Espresso?
When performing a self-consistent calculation using Quantum Espresso, you need to specify the lattice parameter of your system in any units you prefer. Since the lattice parameter expressed in angstroms (Å) is smaller than when expressed in atomic units (au), calculations typically take less time when using angstroms. I find this somewhat confusing—are there any differences between these two units, and how do they affect the output results?

Could you provide some timing results for same calculation using Angstrom and using au? I'd NOT expect the timing to be different because of unit used but QE inherently uses Bohr radius (au). So I'd guess if any calculation is slightly faster, it should be the au one, not the Angstrom one.

For example for Si a = 5.44370 \ang it takes 3.63s CPU      4.27s WALL , while for a = 10.28710 au it takes 48.24s CPU     51.44s WALL. Note: I provided the atomic positions in ATOMIC_POSITIONS in units of alat for both cases.

You should confirm these give the same energy as well.  There is no logical reason why the units should matter here if they are being respected.  I fear you are accidently still getting the cell in angstroms.

@JoeRobert the discrepancy is huge! It shouldn't be the case. Something else is likely to be the cause. Please provide the full input files for both of the calculations

@AbdulMuhaymin Here is the content of input file &SYSTEM     a           = 5.44370     degauss     = 1.00000e-02     ecutrho     = 7.00000e+02     ecutwfc     = 7.00000e+01     ibrav       = 2     nat         = 2     ntyp        = 1     occupations = "fixed"     smearing    = "gaussian" and `ATOMIC_SPECIES
Si     28.08550  Si.pbesol-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {alat}
Si      0.00   0.00   0.00
Si      0.25   0.25   0.25
K_POINTS {automatic}
8  8  8  0 0 0I have just changeda = 5.44370 angora = 10.28710 au`

Your following input file is correct when you meant a = 5.44370 Angstrom. However, you cannot simply change the unit as a = 10.28710 au. The unit of a is always in Angstrom. If you want to express the lattice parameter in au instead of Angstrom, you have to use celldm(1) = 10.28710. See celldm and a in the QE input file description for details.
If you want to use Angstrom:
...
&SYSTEM
     a           = 5.44370  
     ibrav       = 2
     ... 
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {alat} 
    Si      0.00   0.00   0.00 
    Si      0.25   0.25   0.25  
...

If you want to use au (Bohr radius):
...
&SYSTEM
     celldm(1)   = 10.28710
     ibrav       = 2
     ... 
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {alat} 
    Si      0.00   0.00   0.00 
    Si      0.25   0.25   0.25
...

Now, these two input files are equivalent. Previously, when you were using a for both of the cases, the code assumes angstrom for both of the cases, as noted by Tristan Maxson in the comment. That means you were treating two completely different system then.

Thank you so much for your great help and explanation. Now I get it.
